# Average of minimum and maximum in set

Tags: terminology

What does one call the average of the minimum and maximum in a set of numbers?

For example, if you have a set $\{0,1,2,3,10\}$:

$\frac{0 + 10}{2} = 5$, which is called the _____________.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two common names are [mid-range, or mid-extreme.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midrange)